# "Here is a list of all (the) modified files." Should I write "the" or not?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, articles, definite-articles

In this sentence:

> Here is a list of all modified files.

Do I write *the* before *modified* or not ?

I know that plural nouns often lose the article, but I'm not sure with this sentence.

Comment: Both are possible. There is no indefinite plural article, so _a file_ -> _files_, but _the file_ -> _the files_.